# Start and stop tomcat through ant script which is running in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, tomcat

I am trying to start and stop my tomcat through ant build.xml as follows,

I am running the ant script in cygwin , i get the following error
D:\build-cygwin-copy_converted.xml:53: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "shutdown.sh" (in directory "D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to correct the path to `/cygdrive/d/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/bin`